# Open With Explorer Greyed Out SharePoint 2013 on premise

Tags: custom-masterpage, sharepoint-on-prem, open-with-explorer

I have a SharePoint 2013 on premise installation and I have created a custom master page however this is preventing the "open with explorer" button from working. I have a number of team sites so I have therefore set the custom master page as the site master and the system master.

I am finding that when setting the system master back to Seattle of Oslo then the open with explore button works however when changing it back to the custom master which is requires to be then it stops working.

Is it possible that there is some sort of snippet or code missing from my custom master page if so could someone please advise on what may be missing and how best to resolve this?

Comment: Ensure that your custom master page is supporting browser (IE 8+).

Comment: Hi Dikesh, the master page has been built using the latest version of bootstrap which as far as I am aware does support IE 8!

Comment: May be you can get some reference from here - https://newsignature.com/articles/open-with-explorer-errors-in-sharepoint-2010